# How to make a list of all objs of a class in python

Tags: python, class, oop

I want to have in my class a list of all objects that already been created. In my head it makes sense, because lists in Python only saves the local in memory where the object is. In this way, I could have a object in many lists, if I want.

```
class foo:
    bar = []
    def __init__(self):
        bar.append(self)
```

I know this code is wrong, but I know Python wouldn't disappoint me. How could I make it?

EDIT:
Here it is the error message:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-b640dd81ce90> in <module>()
----> 1 b = foo()

<ipython-input-6-15f2b8409770> in __init__(self)
      2     bar = []
      3     def __init__(self):
----> 4         bar.append(self)

NameError: name 'bar' is not defined
```

Comment: Why is this code wrong? I think it does exactly what you want.

Comment: There's an argument to be made for using `foo.bar` (or `type(self).bar`) to be explicit that you are appending to the *class* attribute named `bar`, not an instance attribute of the same name, but this is otherwise the right idea.

Comment: I edited the code, because it was creating a instance variable named bar.

Comment: Your previous code was correct and would not have made an instance variable. `bar` on its own definitely won't work.

Comment: @AlexHall I want a single list `bar` for all instances.

Comment: Here is a demo of your previous code working: https://repl.it/repls/LoneSaddlebrownAggregators

Comment: @Aran-Fey why did you edit out the python 3 tag?

Comment: @AlexHall Because it's not a question about anything specific to python 3. Version tags don't exist to indicate which python version the OP is using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding, but your example seems to work as you intend:

```
class Foo:
    bar = []
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.x = a
        self.bar.append(self)

obj_one = Foo(1)
obj_two = Foo(2)

objects = Foo.bar
for obj in objects:
    print(obj.x)
```

`1`

`2`

Every object will have a copy the list, but as you said, they are just references to objects in memory, so shouldn't be that heavy.

Comment: It works! But I don't know why. To me, it seems Python is creating a new `bar` variable for each instance.

Comment: I spaced out for a minute...  this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: There is only one instance of `bar` as it is a class property, not an instance property.  All the instances can "see" `bar`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does what you are trying to achieve:

```
all_foos = []
class foo:
    def __init__(self):
        all_foos.append(self)
        setattr(self, 'all_foos', all_foos)

foo1 = foo() # Create foo1
foo2 = foo() # Create foo2
print(foo2.all_foos)
```

Outputs:

```
[<__main__.foo object at 0x7feeeeb0fc18>, <__main__.foo object at 0x7feeeeb0fb38>]
```

(The two objects^)

Answer (score 1):

Although Aaron's answer technically works I believe, all you actually need to modify from your original code is the inclusion of `self.` before your `bar.append`.

This creates a "static" variable of sorts in your `foo` class that can be accessed from any instance, or from the class itself.

Here is the code.

```
>>> class foo:
...     bar = []
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.bar.append(self)
... 
>>> a = foo()
>>> id(a)
139971700338984
>>> b = foo()
>>> id(b)
139971700338872
>>> [id(i) for i in foo.bar]
[139971700338984, 139971700338872]
```